# Python fixed delimited text file to csv using struct

Tags: python, csv, struct

I am trying to export some data with the following format

```
    Sat Jan  3 18:15:05 2009    62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18    4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b +              50.00000000
```

into a csv with the following format

```
Fri Jan  9 03:23:48 2009,c1c6cb1b7d3c5a3f1dbd79ebd80d29bc6145e2fc,63522845d294ee9b0188ae5cac91bf389a0c3723f084ca1025e7d9cdfe481ce1,+,              50.00000000
```

unfortunately this is what I get

```
(,',F,r,i, ,J,a,n, , ,9, ,0,3,:,2,3,:,4,8, ,2,0,0,9,',",", ,',c,1,c,6,c,b,1,b,7,d,3,c,5,a,3,f,1,d,b,d,7,9,e,b,d,8,0,d,2,9,b,c,6,1,4,5,e,2,f,c,',",", ,',6,3,5,2,2,8,4,5,d,2,9,4,e,e,9,b,0,1,8,8,a,e,5,c,a,c,9,1,b,f,3,8,9,a,0,c,3,7,2,3,f,0,8,4,c,a,1,0,2,5,e,7,d,9,c,d,f,e,4,8,1,c,e,1,',",", ,',+,',",", ,', , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,5,0,.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,',)
```

and here is my code

```
import csv
import struct

fieldwidths = (-4, 24, -4, 40,-4,64,-1,1,25)  # negative widths represent ignored padding fields
fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's')
                        for fw in fieldwidths)
fieldstruct = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
parse = fieldstruct.unpack_from

c = csv.writer(open("/home/ulrich/Desktop/disertation/sample_parsed_blch1.csv", "wb"))
fields = parse("    Sat Jan  3 18:15:05 2009    62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18    4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b +              50.00000000")

c.writerow(format(fields))
```

Comment: `fields` doesn't exist. What is it supposed to be? I think the error is clear, though. `format` turns whatever `fields` is into a string then `writerow` enumerates the string character by character to produce the csv fields.

Comment: Instead of using `struct`, you could simply slice the string, using the known widths. E.g. `field1 = line[4:28]; field2 = line[32:72];` etc.  If you put the starting position and lengths in a sequence of tuples, such as `sizes = [(4, 24), (32, 40), ...]`, you could write `fields = [line[start:start+length] for start, length in sizes]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you format `fields` into a string. `writerow` treats every element of the collection passed into it as a column in the csv row. For a single string, that means every character is a separate column. Assuming `fields` is the result of parsing the line, just use it directly.

```
import csv
import struct

fieldwidths = (-4, 24, -4, 40,-4,64,-1,1,25)  # negative widths represent ignored padding fields
fmtstring = ' '.join('{}{}'.format(abs(fw), 'x' if fw < 0 else 's')
                        for fw in fieldwidths)
fieldstruct = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
parse = fieldstruct.unpack_from

c = csv.writer(open("/home/ulrich/Desktop/disertation/sample_parsed_blch1.csv", "wb"))
fields = parse("    Sat Jan  3 18:15:05 2009    62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18    4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b +              50.00000000")

c.writerow(fields)
```